# Why am I getting WEB-INF included in WEB-INF/classes when I turn on <attachClasses>?

Tags: java, maven

My source directory is `<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>` and the web app lives in `src/main/webapp` maven wasn't including the compiled `src/main/java` as `WEV-INF/classes` so I turned on `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` which includes `assets` and `WEB-INF` beyond just the classes:

```
project
  WEB-INF
    classes
      WEB-INF
      com[..]
      assets
```

How do I make it only include the compiled classes from `src/main/java`?

Comment: Which plugin are you using to configure this?

Comment: Show your pom file please...